# Why my foreign key is null when saving to h2 db, using JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

What is the difference between these 2 codes. The 1st one shows null on my foreign key which is individualId. The 2nd one is not. Why?

//1st code:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Individual {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "INDIVIDUAL_ID")
    private Long individualId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="individual",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Identification> identifications = new ArrayList<Identification>();
}

@Entity
public class Identification {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "IDT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="individualId")
    private Individual individual;
```

//second code

//replaced @OneToMany in the first code & then i just dont add @ManyToOne in the Identification Class and it works fine. Why?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "INDIVIDUAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "INDIVIDUAL_ID")
private List<Identification> identifications = new ArrayList<Identification>();
```

When i search for JPA tutorial in google the 1st code is the one that i always read. declare @OneToMany in the parent class and add mappedBy, declare @ManyToOne in the child class. But why the 2nd code works perfect than the 1st code? it just let me declare @OneToMany only in the parent class ?

Comment: you say some persistence doesnt work but havent posted the actual persistence code, how the objects are created, what is set and what isnt set, what SQL is issued.

Comment: the objects are created when i fill up the input textbox in the frontend. The objects are passed via angularjs. SQL used for now is spring.jpa.show-sql = true , datasource is org.h2

Answer (score 0):

In the class `Identification` the name of the `@JoinColumn` does not match any column in your class `Individual`. It must be the name of the column in the database, which is INDIVIDUAL_ID:

```
@JoinColumn(name="INDIVIDUAL_ID")
```

Comment: still the same, INDIVIDUAL_ID is null

Comment: Even I am facing this issue.